# Android activity refreshes flow

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A, it has a button to open B, which inserts a record. A can then refresh the view inside onActivityResult. This is a normal flow.

However, B can accept **share intent** to insert a record also. How can A know when this action is done from B to refresh the view just like the normal flow? (of course, I assume act A already running on background task)

I can, of course, detect the change using onResume inside A, but i wish to know if it is a proper method.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onResume to refresh the view for activity A. Because other method would be using broadcastReceiver and broadcastIntent and that would create unnecessary load.

You can use sharedPreference to store if data has been changed in Activity B and then in onResume of Activity A fetch that shared Preference and refresh the view

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isChanged = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isChanged",false);
    if(isChanged){
        //refresh your views
        //clear the shared prefernce
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isChanged",false);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Remember you have set that shared preference in ActivityB while loading data

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isChanged",true);
    editor.apply();
```